# Calling a stored procedure using LINQ to SQL with a Custom Entity Class

Tags: .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Am trying to get linq to call a stored procedure. I know this is usually rather simple, but in this case i am using my own Custom Entity Classes and I am at a dead end.

the link below will show you how I have my OM setup

[example](http://blog.reamped.net/post/2008/02/21/Custom-Entity-Classes-Using-LINQ-to-SQL-Part-1-DataObjects.aspx)

does any one know how you can call a stored procedure from your own Custom Entity Class?

EDIT:

Forgot two things.

1) this will be a silverlight app 
2) I have tired [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386989.aspx) on MSDN but I get cannot call a security function execption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague so I'm not sure if this will help, but I just ran a little test using the [AdventureWorks db](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) and it seemed to work - I'll post my test code and maybe it'll give you a clue. (This is just fetching 3 columns from the Employee table into a new/custom "EmpTest" class.)

**The stored procedure:**

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Get_Employee]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Employee]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Get_Employee 
    @id int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT EmployeeID, Title, VacationHours from HumanResources.Employee where EmployeeID = @id
END
GO
```

**The LINQ to SQL stored procedure method (put this in your DataContext class):**

```
[Function(Name="dbo.Get_Employee")]
public ISingleResult<EmpTest> Get_Employee([Parameter(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> id)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), id);
    return ((ISingleResult<EmpTest>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

**The custom entity:**

```
[Table(Name = "HumanResources.Employee")]
public class EmpTest
{
    private int _EmployeeID;
    private string _Title;
    private short _VacationHours;

    [Column(Storage = "_EmployeeID", DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get { return this._EmployeeID; }
        set { this._EmployeeID = value; }
    }

    [Column(Storage = "_Title", DbType = "NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Title
    {
        get { return this._Title; }
        set { this._Title = value; }
    }

    [Column(Storage = "_VacationHours", DbType = "SmallInt NOT NULL")]
    public short VacationHours
    {
        get { return this._VacationHours; }
        set { this._VacationHours = value; }
    }
}
```

**And, finally the call:**

```
EmpTest emp = context.Get_Employee(41).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: why work so hard? if you declare a temp table, linq to sql will create a custom result set for you!